# Multiple accounts in Outlook; can I access all of them using IMAP?

Tags: python, imap

Basically, I have 3 accounts that I can access in Outlook, but I only have the username & password for one. Is there any way I can use IMAP to access the other 2 accounts, or do I need credentials? I'm using the python imaplib module, but I don't think that matters.

Comment: When using IMAP you'll require credentials for all mailboxes you wish to access.

Comment: Whether or not you can use them from Outlook doesn't really help resolve this. The server, port, and user name usually keeps accounts distinct. If these are indeed separate IMAP accounts, you will need this information for each, plus the password. Perhaps some of them are POP or Exchange accounts, though?

Comment: I should mention that all 3 accounts are Exchange accounts. I'm just using IMAP to access them.